# Recheck URL after 5 Min with While Statement True

Tags: python

I have a statement that I am using to show data on an LED panel.  After 430 PM it shows time, scrolling text and static text.  The scrolling text is pulled from a form submission and displays on the LED.  What I am trying to accomplish is have the script check every 5 min if an update has happened and then display new text.

```
 else: 
    def run(self):
        offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()
        pos = offscreen_canvas.width
        res = requests.get('https://mysite.io/message/message.php')
        soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
        price = soup.select_one('.message').text
        price2 = "Stock Closed"
        font = graphics.Font()
        font.LoadFont("fonts/5x7.bdf")
        textColor = graphics.Color(255, 255, 0)
        textColor2 = graphics.Color(255, 0, 255)
        text3 = graphics.Color(255, 0, 0)
        my_text = price
        my_text2 = price2
        

        while True:
            offscreen_canvas.Clear()
            my_text1 = "Time: " + strftime("%H:%M", localtime())

            len1 = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, pos, 7, text3, price) <--- Scrolls
            len2 = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, 1, 19, textColor2, my_text1) <--- Static
            len3 = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, 1, 31, textColor, my_text2)  <--- Static
            pos -= 1
            if (pos + len1 < 0 ):
                pos = offscreen_canvas.width
            time.sleep(0.07)
            offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.SwapOnVSync(offscreen_canvas)
```

The above is my current setup.  It only updates once per day.

I have tried the below.

```
        while True:
            offscreen_canvas.Clear()
            my_text1 = "Time: " + strftime("%H:%M", localtime())

            len1 = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, pos, 7, text3, price)
            len2 = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, 1, 19, textColor2, my_text1)
            len3 = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, 1, 31, textColor, my_text2)
            pos -= 1
            if (pos + len1 < 0 ):
                pos = offscreen_canvas.width
            time.sleep(0.07)
            offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.SwapOnVSync(offscreen_canvas)
            self.run()
```

The show the static text but does not scroll the first line.

I have also tried.

```
 else: 

            offscreen_canvas.Clear()
            offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()
            pos = offscreen_canvas.width
            res = requests.get('https://mysite.io/message/message.php')
            soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
            price = soup.select_one('.message').text
            price2 = "Stock Closed"
            font = graphics.Font()
            font.LoadFont("fonts/5x7.bdf")
            textColor = graphics.Color(255, 255, 0)
            textColor2 = graphics.Color(255, 0, 255)
            text3 = graphics.Color(255, 0, 0)
            my_text = price
            my_text2 = price2
            my_text1 = "Time: " + strftime("%H:%M", localtime())

            len1 = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, pos, 7, text3, price)
            len2 = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, 1, 19, textColor2, my_text1)
            len3 = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, 1, 31, textColor, my_text2)
            pos -= 1
            if (pos + len1 < 0 ):
                pos = offscreen_canvas.width
            time.sleep(0.07)
            offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.SwapOnVSync(offscreen_canvas)
```

The above updates immediately but the scrolling is very very slow.

So the objective is to have it scroll smooth and update every x minutes.
Maybe not using beautifulsoup will speed it up so another suggestion would also be welcome.

Thanks for the help guys.